# Node-sass what is the diffence between these versions?

Tags: node-sass

There are multiple node-sass binary versions at their [release page](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases).

What is the difference between `win32-x64-48_binding.node` and `win32-x64-51_binding.node`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "48" and "51" are the node versions that the binaries are compiled against. You can see what version it refers to by looking at https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/